# JPA-Hibernate Join table Inheritance cannot query subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to query the subclass by the parent attributes. However hibernate always try to map the query result to parent class.

Framework used: JPA 2.0, Hibernate 3, Spring 3

Exception thrown:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: Object with id: com.hkbea.zpm.entity.PositionPk@1dee9de was not of the specified subclass: com.hkbea.zpm.entity.FundPosition (loaded object was of wrong class class com.hkbea.zpm.entity.Position); nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: com.hkbea.zpm.entity.PositionPk@1dee9de was not of the specified subclass: com.hkbea.zpm.entity.FundPosition (loaded object was of wrong class class com.hkbea.zpm.entity.Position)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:666)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.convertHibernateAccessException(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:303)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:282)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getFundListByAccountNumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.service.impl.OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.adjustCashForRedeemUT(OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.java:1224)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.service.impl.OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.getTRB(OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.java:248)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.service.impl.OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.getTRB(OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.java:219)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.service.impl.OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.calculateHandler(OnlineInterfaceServiceImpl.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.calculateHandler(Unknown Source)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.controller.OnlineInterfaceController.calculate(OnlineInterfaceController.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.ext.spring.ZPMAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(ZPMAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:429)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.ext.spring.ZPMAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(ZPMAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:417)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.hkbea.zpm.session.ZPMLoginFilter.doFilter(ZPMLoginFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've set the hibernate.show_sql to true and checked the sql seems alright and is expected when i try to execute in sql client.

```sql
    select
        fundpositi0_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY49_,
        fundpositi0_.MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER as MAIN1_49_,
        fundpositi0_.REFERENCE as REFERENCE49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER as ACCOUNT3_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_EXT as ACCOUNT4_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.ACTIVE_FLAG as ACTIVE5_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.BASE_MARKET_VALUE as BASE6_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.CREATE_TIMESTAMP as CREATE7_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.CREATE_USER as CREATE8_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.CURRENCY as CURRENCY49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIP10_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.EXCHANGE_RATE as EXCHANGE11_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.LDS_TYPE as LDS12_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.MARKET_VALUE as MARKET13_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.NEW_RISK_RATING as NEW14_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.QUANTITY as QUANTITY49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.RISK_RATING as RISK16_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.UNIT_PRICE as UNIT17_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as UPDATE18_49_,
        fundpositi0_1_.UPDATE_USER as UPDATE19_49_,
        fundpositi0_.AVAILABLE_BALANCE as AVAILABLE1_75_,
        fundpositi0_.AVERAGE_COST as AVERAGE2_75_,
        fundpositi0_.BASE_PROFIT_LOSS as BASE3_75_,
        fundpositi0_.INSTRUMENT_NAME as INSTRUMENT4_75_,
        fundpositi0_.ISIN_CODE as ISIN5_75_,
        fundpositi0_.LAST_QUANTITY as LAST6_75_,
        fundpositi0_.PROFIT_LOSS as PROFIT7_75_,
        fundpositi0_.QUANTITY_HELD as QUANTITY8_75_,
        fundpositi0_.SCS_SECURITY_CODE as SCS9_75_ 
    from
        PBWMS_FUND_POS fundpositi0_,
        PBWMS_POS fundpositi0_1_ 
    where
        fundpositi0_.CATEGORY=fundpositi0_1_.CATEGORY 
        and fundpositi0_.MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER=fundpositi0_1_.MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
        and fundpositi0_.REFERENCE=fundpositi0_1_.REFERENCE 
        and fundpositi0_1_.ACTIVE_FLAG='A' 
        and fundpositi0_1_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER=?
```

I've tried to change the parent class to abstract, but hibernate will throw exception for failed to instantiate object of abstract class.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: com.hkbea.zpm.entity.Position
```

I've also searched some other post said, the cascade mode need to be set for many-to-one property. So i have tried but still not working.

Query:

```java
(List<FundPosition>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("from FundPosition where activeFlag='A' and accountNumber=?")
    .setString(0, accountNumber)
    .list();
```

Parent Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="PBWMS_POS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Position extends BaseEntityObject
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5370267130957236544L;

    @Id
    protected PositionPk pk;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    protected CustomerAccount customerAccount;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER", nullable=false)
    protected String accountNumber;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER_EXT", nullable=false)
    protected String accountNumberExt;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable=false)
    protected String description;

    @Column(name="CURRENCY", nullable=false)
    protected String currency;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    protected BigDecimal quantity;

    @Column(name="UNIT_PRICE")
    protected BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name="EXCHANGE_RATE", scale=6, precision=8)
    protected BigDecimal exchangeRate;

    @Column(name="MARKET_VALUE")
    protected BigDecimal marketValue;

    @Column(name="BASE_MARKET_VALUE")
    protected BigDecimal baseMarketValue;

    @Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG", nullable=false, length=1)
    protected String activeFlag;

    @Column(name="CREATE_USER", nullable=false)
    protected String createUser;

    @Column(name="CREATE_TIMESTAMP")
    protected Timestamp createTimestamp;

    @Column(name="UPDATE_USER")
    protected String updateUser;

    @Column(name="UPDATE_TIMESTAMP")
    protected Timestamp updateTimestamp;

    @Column(name="RISK_RATING")
    protected String riskRating; 

    @Column(name="NEW_RISK_RATING")
    protected String newRiskRating;

    @Column(name="LDS_TYPE")
    protected String ldsType;

        //getters and setters...
}
```

Child Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="PBWMS_FUND_POS")
public class FundPosition extends Position
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8143748295075339416L;

    @Column(name="ISIN_CODE", nullable=false)
    private String isinCode;

    @Column(name="INSTRUMENT_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String instrumentName;

    @Column(name="SCS_SECURITY_CODE", nullable=false)
    private String scsSecurityCode;

    @Column(name="AVAILABLE_BALANCE", nullable=false)
    private BigDecimal availableBalance;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY_HELD", nullable=false)
    private BigDecimal quantityHeld;

    @Column(name="AVERAGE_COST")
    private BigDecimal averageCost;

    @Column(name="PROFIT_LOSS")
    private BigDecimal profitLoss;

    @Column(name="BASE_PROFIT_LOSS")
    private BigDecimal baseProfitLoss;

    @Column(name="LAST_QUANTITY")
    private BigDecimal lastQuantity;

        //getters and setters...
}
```

Composite Key Class:

```java
@Embeddable
public class PositionPk implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9161644029517397019L;

    @Column(name="MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    protected String mainAccountNumber;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY")
    protected Category category;

    @Column(name="REFERENCE")
    protected String reference;

        //equals, getters and setters...
}
```

BaseEntityObject Class:

```java
...
import net.sf.gilead.pojo.java5.LightEntity;

public abstract class BaseEntityObject extends LightEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7453050794164673008L;

    @Transient
    public Object getUnderlyingValue()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void setUnderlyingValue(Object obj)
    {

    }

    @Transient
    public String getDebugString()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void setDebugString(String str)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

Update on 2019-08-15,
Also tried to add following annotations in subclass, still not working

```java
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER", referencedColumnName="MAIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="REFERENCE", referencedColumnName="REFERENCE"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CATEGORY", referencedColumnName="CATEGORY")

})
```

Comment: Can you show your `BaseEntityObject`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  Sure